# Couchdb in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, couchdb

I am just getting started with couchdb in nodejs. I am looking for a tutorial or article that would help me get started or at least some lines of code. I don't want to use any module for db abstraction because that would defeat the purpose of learning . I am looking to make my own module that works with Couch and from my understanding this could easily be accomplished with the request module https://github.com/mikeal/request but I haven't found anything about this. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a blog post about this, hope it's helpful to you:

http://writings.nunojob.com/2011/09/getting-started-with-nodejs-and-couchdb.html

Comment: I've actually looked through your module last night trying to figure out how things are working :D

Answer (score 4):

Check out Nano: https://github.com/dscape/nano

It's exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this module: https://github.com/cloudhead/cradle it's very helpful to getting started with couchdb on nodejs.
Just take a look at the main readme on github

Answer (score 1):

For getting started with working with CouchDB without a nice in-between like `cradle`, I'd recommend [*CouchDB: The Definitive Guide*](http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/index.html).  It helped me immensely when developing [CouchQueue](https://github.com/jdotjdot/couchQueue), a Node.js module for creating queues out of CouchDB databases.

Answer (score 1):

Nano is the simplest way to interact with CouchDB.
http://www.tutorialindustry.com/node-js-couchdb-tutorial-for-beginners

You can also go for Cradle(A high-level, caching, CouchDB client for Node.js)-https://github.com/cloudhead/cradle

Comment: The first link in this answer is no longer accessible