# Electron Desktop Application communicating with remote NoSql server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, electron, couchdb, desktop-application

I've begun to dive into developing a desktop application with electron. I have been interested in pairing this application with a NoSQL database to create users, display data, and do CRUD operations. I've considered databases such as MongoDB and CouchDB, and I'm curious if creating a desktop application that communicates with a database hosted elsewhere is a feasible goal.

I'm hoping that someone here can help direct me to great resources on creating a desktop application that works with a remote NoSQL database. Any advice here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Many desktop applications communicate with remote databases, so any guide on these databases would help you. There are questions on Stackoverflow such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250383/couchdb-in-nodejs

Comment: I'll definitely check these out, thank you!

Comment: You can also check out AceBase, which is an open-source realtime NoSQL database engine for node.js. If you want your app to reliably sync with a server or other clients in realtime, or after having been used offline, AceBase is definitely worth taking a look at: https://github.com/appy-one/acebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the use of [CouchDB](https://couchdb.apache.org/), which uses a `JSON` based document format. CouchDB bundles the server and data storage functionality in a single product, providing a REST-like **HTTP interface** for document insertion, updates, retrieval and deletion.

Therefore, you'll be able to interact with CouchDB directly from within the Electron desktop application. [Apache CouchDB Nano](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano) is the official Node.js library for accessing CouchDB.

The following additional factors speach for CouchDB:

- It is open source.
- It has comprehensive documentation.
- It is available for Linux, macOS and Windows.
- It's easily installed and quickly set up.
- It can be installed on your local computer (for development), on your own servers, or in the cloud.
- It supports [Mango](https://github.com/cloudant/mango) querying language (inspired from MongoDB).
- It is highly scalable.
- It is shipped with [Fauxton](https://couchdb.apache.org/fauxton-visual-guide/index.html) web interface that lets you create, update, delete, view and query documents on the fly.
- etc.

Comment: This is wonderful information, thank you so much. I kept going back and forth between MongoDB and CouchDB but kept gravitating towards CouchDB. I am excited to give it a shot with an Electron app. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help you in taking a reasonable decision.